# Azure Search service long running index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have created a Blob storage in which 1000s of .pdf files stored. I have verified for 600 documents, It was working fine. so I started for all documents stored in the blobs. I saw after 16 hours it was still running but there is no process document count, so I deleted the service. It was successfully deleted. Now I have created new service but its not working any way.

[Confguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN2UE.png)

Comment: Please share what configuration details that you can for what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: POST https://search.windows.net/indexers?api-version=2016-09-01
api-key----------
{
"@odata.context": "https://search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "0x8D54E02030217BE",
"name": "prod-media-indexer",
"description": "",
"dataSourceName": "prod-media-ds",
"targetIndexName": "prod-media-index",
"schedule": {
"interval": "P1D",
"startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},

Comment: "parameters": {
"batchSize": null,
"maxFailedItems": 100,
"maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 100,
"base64EncodeKeys": false,

Comment: "configuration": {
"dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
"excludedFileNameExtensions": ".mp4,.rar,.f4v,.wmv,.swf,.xlsb,.ppsx,.ani,.bmp,.cal,.fax,.gif,.img,.jbg,.jpe,.jpeg,.jpg,.mac,.pbm,.pcd,.pcx,.pct,.pgm,.png,.ppm,.psd,.ras,.tga,.tiff,.wmf,.html,.htm,.rtf,.eml,.zip,.json,.xml,.csv",
"indexedFileNameExtensions": ".pdf,.docx,.doc,.ppt,.pptx,.xlsx,.xls",
"failOnUnsupportedContentType": false
}
},

Comment: "fieldMappings": [
  {
"sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
"targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
"mappingFunction": {
"name": "base64Encode",
"parameters": null
}
}
],
"disabled": null
}

Comment: Configurations are associated with question

Comment: put them in your question and not the comments.

Comment: Please see image name Configuration in posted question

Comment: The configuration is correct, I have checked in other environment, Its working and processing the files.

Comment: put the code/configuration in the question directly and not as an image.

Comment: We followed up on your [question on MDSN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ec20c8a9-2382-4c1c-ba97-1202ad25e4cc/issue-in-long-running-indexer?forum=azuresearch). Please don't cross post in the future since it just creates more work for all involved.